# Getting REG Hive List of an offline Device

Tags: command-line, batch, windows-registry, winpe

I am trying to get an hive list files of an offline windows installation so I can backup the files in WINPE in my script.

What I have tried

```
reg load HKLM\Offline D:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM
regedit
```

Then when I go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Offline\ControlSet001\Control` the hivelist value is missing. Where is this stored at if it's not in the SYSTEM hive? I have tried loading all other hives from the hive list generated when the device was online to no avail.

WinPE: windows 11 x64
Windows Offline Version: windows 11 x64